# Is housewares a double plural?

Tags: irregular-plurals

Of all the words ending in 'ware', ***housewares*** is the only one that gets an ending 's'.

- cookware
- earthenware
- flatware
- glassware
- hardware
- shareware
- silverware
- software
- stoneware
- tableware
- tupperware

What is the reason for this exception?  Or, what is the grammatical explanation for it?

The definition of 'ware' is plural: manufactured articles

Putting an 's' on the end of ware seems redundantly plural, as in housewares.

Comment: Accident? **Ware** was a word that appeared in singular or plural, and there are other *ware* words that have a plural form. (**Small wares**). Turns out **smallwares** is a formation used in marketing and restaurants. ( https://marketing-dictionary.org/s/smallwares/ )

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin Yes, and in fact there seems to be no settled usage.  In online Merriam, it has only the plural form.  Many advertisements proclaim “housewares”.  But I am not sure they should.  Jury’s out.

Comment: Brasswares, earthenwares, ironwares,...  This search gave me 200 of these (although some are verbs): https://onelook.com/?w=*wares&first=1

Comment: I've checked all your examples down to 'hardware' in Wiktionary, the least venerable? bravest? most up-to-date? of dictionaries considered pretty reliable (again (?)) on the internet, and 'hardware' is the first it doesn't say has both count and non-count usages. And I'd guess this will soon change too. You'd better state what the definition of 'double plural' you're using is. / Note that 'The silverwares of the Georgian and Victorian periods show quite significant differences' (a plural again allowed by Wiktionary) shows an example of the common phenomenon known as _countification_. // ...

Comment: Note also that 'the definition of "team" "is plural" ': the players [at the club etc involved] [or a specified subset]. Please check previous threads discussing count and non-count  usages, plural forms, agreement, and **etic countability** (my furniture [non-count usage] may consist of 7 items: a bed, 2 tables and 4 chairs; these items are etically countable). And how these don't all logically match up.

Answer (score 1):

Explaining why one thing changes and another doesn't is hard because these changes are often arbitrary. Take this as a partial answer.

**Wares** is used when there are multiple kinds of *-ware* being offered, such that a form with **wares** serves as a hypernym of many kinds of *-ware*. For instance, the first two definitions for "[ware, n.3](https://oed.com/view/Entry/22569)" in the Oxford English Dictionary distinguish the collective form in singular and plural. Earlier uses of both forms go back to Old English. See what happens in the last three entries for each:

**Singular**

> c1820   Nursery Rime   Simple Simon Met a Pyeman, Going to the Fair;
>   Says Simple Simon To the Pyeman, Let me taste your **ware**.
>
> 1823   W. Scott Peveril IV. vii. 162   I am always provided with **ware**
>   which a gentleman may risk his life on. (note: fulltext [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/5959/5959-h/5959-h.htm) shows that a cutler is speaking)
>
> 1844   A. W. Kinglake Eothen xviii. 299   The owners raised various
>   objections to the display of their **ware** [sc. white slave-girls].

The *ware* in later use refers to a specific kind of good - pie, cutlery, or slave.

**Plural**

> 1776   A. Smith Inq. Wealth of Nations II. iv. ii. 52   A capricious
>   man of fashion might sometimes prefer foreign wares, merely because
>   they were foreign, to cheaper and better goods of the same kind that
>   were made at home.
>
> 1834   G. P. R. James John Marston Hall I. xii. 159   I perceived..a
>   man in the dress of a pedlar, with his box of wares laid down by his
>   side.
>
> 1913   G. Edmundson Church Rome First Cent. v. 123   A fire broke
>   out..amidst shops containing inflammable wares.

In later use, all of these *wares* are made up of several kinds of goods, or goods of indistinct type - Adam Smith is discussing *goods* generally, the peddler-dressed man may sell several kinds of goods, and the shops collectively may sell several kinds of goods that are inflammable.

This shift to a distinction between *ware* and *wares* feels recent, over the last few centuries. For example, almost a century before the 1834 example, a similar example involving a peddler appeared in singular, even though he would presumably sell several kinds of goods:

> 1748   T. Smollett Roderick Random I. viii. 55   He certainly intended to make free with the pedlar's **ware**.

**Houseware(s)** formed as a word at the time this shift in form was occurring. In the earliest example offered by the OED, under "[house, n.1 and int.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/88886?redirectedFrom=housewares#eid1351646)," **houseware** is singular:

> 1827   T. Carlyle tr. J. P. F. Richter in German Romance III. 87   I..wished that..I had given up the stupid **houseware** to all thieves and fires.

However, almost all later uses are in plural, save for one example of an appositive noun in singular:

> 1859   W. Barnes Views Labour & Gold 141   **House-wares**, that are now
>   in shops of every town and village, were borne on strings of
>   packhorses from fair to fair.
>
> 1921   Daily Colonist (Victoria, Brit. Columbia) 1 Apr. 7/1 (advt.)
>   Extra values in reliable **house wares** today and Saturday.
>
> 1971   Sunday Express (Johannesburg) 28 Mar. (Home Jrnl.) 9/3 (advt.) 
>   **Housewares**..Grapefruit knife..Bathroom Scales.
>
> 1990   Essentials Sept. 4/2   Pack your kids off to a new term with
>   a..lunchkit from Thermos... The lunchkits cost £4.99 from department
>   and **houseware stores**.
>
> 2005   N.Y. Times (National ed.) 20 Nov. v. 10/1   Shops like Colette,
>   in Paris, where a selective collection of high-end **housewares**,
>   clothing, CD's and art books are displayed side by side.

**Housewares** becomes a convenient shorthand for all the  kinds of *ware* that appear in a home, following from the developing usage of **wares** compared to **ware**. At least one other word fits the pattern, and has been enshrined in bureaucratic use: smallwares ([IRS](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/smallwares)):

> Generally smallwares consists of the following categories: glassware, flatware, dinnerware, pots and pans, table top items, bar supplies, food preparation utensils and tools, storage supplies, service items and small appliances costing $500 or less.

As to the other question, it is hard to draw a strict line between *hypernym* and not, and therefore to explain why more words don't use **wares**. For example, **kitchenware** would serve as a hypernym of various utensils and appliances, including *silverware* and *earthenware*, but it maintains a singular form. So there is an element of arbitrariness afoot.

Comment: I see no shift in meaning at all.

Comment: @Lambie Not even in context? A pieman, a cutler, and a slaver sell one ware. Importers, peddlers, and several shops sell multiple wares

Comment: "sell one ware or a single ware" and "sell wares" have the same meaning....

Comment: Today, *ware* and *wares* differ in number of kind of good. The forms are not interchangeable today. Before the 18th century, you might have encountered "sell ware" in the way you just used "sell wares." "1697   J. Dryden tr. Virgil Pastorals iv, in tr. Virgil Wks. 18   No Keel shall cut the Waves for **foreign Ware**." "1484   W. Caxton tr. Subtyl Historyes & Fables Esope i   The merchaunt of Baldak came in to egypte for to chepe & bye **somme ware** or marchaundyse." If you're pointing out that I use "meaning" rather than "form," I'll change it.

Comment: ware or wares today is mostly para-literary for product or products.

Answer (score 0):

According to Fowler's these are noncount or "mass nouns," in the sense of "a type of" or "a quantity of".  Thus, *housewares* suggests a variety of wares.  Notice that some of the "wares" in your list are indeed hyponyms of housewares.

There's a classic example.  *Fish* is both singular and plural, except when referring to different species.  Then the word is *fishes*—for example, *a field guide to tropical fishes*.  Meat becomes meats to allude to different kinds of meat.

So, in general, your "double plural" form is useful for noncount nouns if you want to emphasize variety, which can be useful in science and commerce.